# Free watermark for my wizards.Where can I find them?

Tags: c#

I have written some wizards in c# and I would like to make look like more professional by adding some watermarks on the welcome and complete page.

I am struggling to find any source where I can download some free to use EG Database related watermarks that I can use in a Database script generator that I have written.
Any suggestions?

I am pretty useless at making them.

thanks

PS
Not sure where I should post it .I put under c# but again not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to download watermark tools, these links might be helpful:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Others/Fast-Watermark-Free.shtml

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/20/download-free-watermark-image-to-watermark-or-add-logo-to-photos-in-batch/

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Best/free-watermark.html

And you can search for more on Google. Don't forget to scan these tools for spyware, etc.

Or you can create your own watermark here: http://www.webwatermarks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please consider checking Google. When I looked up "Free Watermarks" there were several viable hits.

Also try looking into "Stock Photography" and some combination thereof with "Free Watermarks"

Comment: Hi,I did google and typed exactly that but wondering if somebody new some specific links etc....